# Drupal 6: sort display of node references

Tags: drupal

I have a content type that references multiple nodes, and I need a way to sort the display of those referenced nodes.

Any ideas?

--- EDIT ---
Clarification:

I'm not using views, but rather am using my own queries.

I have a bunch of teachers (teacher content-type), and some conferences (conference content-type).

Within the conference content-type I want a node-reference field set to handle multiple teacher selections.  But I need to be able to manually order them independently. What that means is that each individual conference needs to be able to sort the order of the particular teachers selected.

That's the ideal situation, but not the way I'm actually doing it.

What I'm ACTUALLY doing to jury-rig this thing is to have separate node-reference fields (teacher 1, teacher 2, teacher 3 etc.).  Each node-reference field independent of the others.

It makes for a mess when it comes to creating views or composing db queries.

I know what I'm looking for is all but impossible, but I thought I'd run it by the Drupal gurus here anyway...

--- EDIT 2 ---
Further clarification:

Another way to do what I want, but is really impractical, is to create a separate nodequeue for each conference. Then you could select a handful of teachers associated with each conference and order them via the nodequeue. - That should help with visualizing the problem.  But as a solution, it's even more messy (in terms of administration) than the one I'm currently using.

Also: I should mention that we're talking about 40 to 80 conferences, and 100-200 teachers.  Just to get an idea of why I'm looking for a more elegant solution than the two I mentioned above.

Comment: I don't know did I understand you, but did you try creat View with sorting?

Comment: If you are coding then show the code.

Comment: Show the code for what exactly? Some of the current db queries I use in my current configuration?  I don't know how that would help my question.

Comment: Hrm, then I do not know what you are asking. Some query builder that is not Views? EntityFieldQuery only exists in Drupal 7 but that only works on a singular entity and so you definitely wont be able to order entities on some property of referenced entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node reference with autocomplete widget gives you reordering capabilities when number of values set to 'unlimited'. Maybe not the most comfortable, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Views since you mentioned "displays". You can always change the order of the view fields from the Views UI but the order will be static (all items will have the same order).

If you want each item to have a potentially different order for the fields maybe you can set up a parent child relationship where the child item is ordered dynamically.

Comment: Please see above for clarification.